# Docker nginx healthcheck failing but script works when healthcheck not defined

Tags: docker, nginx

We have an issue where we have defined a docker healthcheck for an Nginx container in a docker-compose file. The healthcheck just runs a node js script which performs an https api call on the endpoint of the nginx container. 
The healthcheck fails due to http timeout. If we exec inside the nginx container and run 'node nginxcheck.js' we get the same timeout. The application itself is run in a single node swarm ( docker stack deploy) but its the same even if we just run docker-compose up

The strange thing is when the healthcheck is not defined in docker-compose then we can exec in and run the script and it passes fine. Again its just performing an https request on itself. So we know the script is OK and it works.

Its as if defining the healthcheck itself is obstructing the script. Indeed even trying to contact the endpoint from outside the host fails but all works fine when there is no healthcheck. We tried defining the healthcheck in the Dockerfile but it makes no difference. Below is a snippet of how we've defined it

```
  nginx:
    image: nginxdev
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
      condition: on-failure
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
     test: node ./etc/nginx/nginxcheck.js
     interval: 120s
     timeout: 60s
     retries: 1
    depends_on:
     - web
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - web
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs
```

Comment: What if you add a --start-period=DURATION_IN_SECONDS (under health check). Put a value that would help all the services (containers) to bootstrap itself?

Comment: We tried a start period of 60 and 120 seconds, it didn't make any difference